# Installing Bootstrap 4 alpha with NPM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

How can I specifically install the Bootstrap 4 Alpha using NPM. Using `npm install bootstrap` only installs the current Version 3.3.5.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out how using package management tool x to install package y could possibly be constituted as "Question asking us to recommend or find a book, tool..." the software isn't unknown, it is known the question is how to install it!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can download `bootstrap v4 alpha` version using the git branch `v4-dev`

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.4
```

or

```
npm install git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git\#v4-dev
```

or

```
npm install https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git\#v4-dev
```

or

```
npm install twbs/bootstrap#v4-dev
```

Comment: Doesn't work using node v5.0.0? Did there anything changed?

Comment: oh, It works though takes more time than it should be.

Comment: The package is downloaded directly from GitHub. Hence its bit slow compared to usual npm package..

Comment: Thanks. If I install using the above commands, It doesn't retrieve all the files from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/grunt. Do you know the reason behind it? also missing docs, js folders.

Comment: @Rashidul in the `package.json` bs ppl have given allowed files as these
`"files": [
    "dist",
    "grunt/*.js",
    "grunt/*.json",
    "js/*.js",
    "scss/**/*.scss",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "LICENSE"
  ],` and only these files are added in the module.     for more info https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files

Answer (score 24):

Use this command

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also install by using the **@next** tag:

```
npm install bootstrap@next --save
```

> The @next tag is used by some projects to identify the upcoming
>   version.

One can view the current tag <=> version mapping by using

```
npm view bootstrap dist-tags
```

or

```
npm dist-tag ls bootstrap
```

and all released bootstrap versions with

```
npm view bootstrap versions
```

> Tags must share a namespace with version numbers, because they are
>   specified in the same slot: `npm install <pkg>@<version>` vs `npm install <pkg>@<tag>`.

More info about the tag system [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) and [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view).

Comment: Note that unlike Manoj's answer this will not be stored this way in the `package.json` when doing `--save`.

Comment: The tags themselves will not be stored, but the tagged versions(e.g. `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6"`).

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't seem to work for me using Node v5 but it does work if you get the tarball directly via http. Downloads really fast too.

```
npm install https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tarball/v4-dev
```

Or by adding this line to your `package.json` file, in the `dependencies` section:

```
"bootstrap": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tarball/v4-dev"
```

It will install successfully:

```
└── bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha
```