# bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.3 invalid

Tags: npm, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Installing bootstrap 4 via npm I keep getting the same error:

[image]

Any ideas how to successfully install bootstrap 4 with npm? I have tried all options from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33480049/3935156)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: Installed it with bower instead and it worked.

`bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.3`

Answer (score 5):

May be you missed to add **--save** after the **npm** command

**Use this**:

> npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.3 --save

**For latest version** :

> npm install bootstrap@next --save

Answer (score 2):

To install bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 using your package.json file, you need to add this to the devDependencies:

```
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"
```

Hope that helps.